# auto.arima() function is slower when parallel is TRUE than when it is never used

Tags: r, parallel-processing, arima

I am presently trying out how to run `auto.arima()` function with parallelization in `R` thinking that it should be more `system time` efficient to include `parallel = TRUE` and `stepwise = FALSE` in the `auto.arima()` function but the reverse is the case when I practice it.

Please look at the way I make my practice and tell me what I am missing that my practice is different from theory.

```
library(forecast)
## When parallel is used
#############################################
system.time({
  for (i in 1:100) {
    x <- arima.sim(n = 50, model=list(ar = 0.8), sd = 1)
    y <- arimaorder(auto.arima(x, ic = "aicc"))
    #print(y)
  }
})[[3]]
#[1] 5.86 

library(parallel)
## When parallel is used
###########################################################
system.time({
  for (i in 1:100) {
    x <- arima.sim(n = 50, model=list(ar = 0.8), sd = 1)
    y <- arimaorder(auto.arima(x, parallel = TRUE, stepwise=FALSE, ic = "aicc"))
    #print(y)
  }
})[[3]]
#[1] 162.86
```

I am operating from Windows 10, 64 bits, 16GB RAM.

Comment: The first model has `stepwise=TRUE`

Comment: `stepwise=TRUE was not included in the model

Comment: `stepwise=TRUE` is the default. As you omit any `stepwise` argument then it is set to `TRUE` hence the models are not directly comparable. Additionally, one thing to consider, if the model search finished quickly then `parallel`methods can take longer due to setting up the process.